# Wordpress use the_content() with out gallery?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to use the_content() excluding the galleries? I want to make this because I need the gallery displayed with flexslider. I already integrate flexslider. If I want to show the content of the post, for example: some text, separated images and of course a gallery. It will display the gallery with flexslider and then the content with the text, images and the gallery again. I don't want the gallery duplicated.

```
<div class="entry-content">

    <?php $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );?>

    <div class="flexslider flexslider-gallery">
        <ul class="slides slides-gallery">
            <?php foreach( $gallery['src'] AS $src ){ ?>    
                <li>
                    <img alt="Gallery image" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" />
                </li>          
            <?php } ?>   
        </ul> <!-- end .slides -->
    </div> <!-- end .flexslider -->  

<?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: you could store the content in a var before you run the get post gallery call. Something like `$content = get_the_content();` - get_post_gallery is probably using query_post which will overwrite the last instance of $post, which will screw up that `the_content()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the solution:

Add to functions.php

```
function remove_shortcode_from($content) {
  $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
  return $content;
}
```

and then call it when you need, in my case in content-gallery.php:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_shortcode_from');
the_content();
remove_filter('the_content', 'remove_shortcode_from')
```

Comment: it removes all shortcode tags from the content not only gallery but that's what i want .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1) The WordPress Gallery is contained in a div with class .gallery. If flexsider does not also use that class, you could simply set your CSS to:

```
.gallery { display: none; }
```

2) You could get the content with get_the_content, parse it using a DOM parser and delete the Gallery.

Option #1 is less efficient, but avoids the complexity of parsing the DOM.

Neither method is guaranteed to work if the site is use a non-standard gallery plugin that is creating non-WP HTML.

Comment: Ok thanks for answer. I think the second method is better. Could you give me an example of that? Thanks in advanced!!!

Comment: I think what's happening is the get_post_gallery call is overwriting the global $post var in wp, so when he is calling the_content() below the gallery, it is actually just echoing the content from the get_post_gallery result